# Q: No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2) after spark-submit

Tags: java, apache-spark, log4j, spark-submit

Quick Start step by step with Apache Spark
but finally show this warn message

```
20/05/25 09:43:05 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

My code is

```
package firstmaven;

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        String logFile = "/data/spark/README.md";
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Simple Application")
                            .config("spark.master","local").getOrCreate();
        Dataset<String> logData = spark.read().textFile(logFile).cache();
        long numAs = logData.filter(s -> s.contains("a")).count();
        long numBs = logData.filter(s -> s.contains("b")).count();
        System.out.println("Lines with a: " + numAs + ", lines with b: " + numBs);

        System.out.println("Hello world");

        spark.stop();
    }
}
```

What should I do to let it work ? Thanks.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Take a tour and get your first badge-https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Those are just warning, are you facing any issues ??

Comment: I don’t see any result about System.out.println. 
Does it work correctly ? 
Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the value of the column by which you want to filter. Check this snippet below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

import java.util.List;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String logFile = "/Users/ajay/input.txt";
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Simple Application")
                .config("spark.master", "local").getOrCreate();
        Dataset<String> logData = spark.read().textFile(logFile).cache();
        List<String> rowList = logData.collectAsList();
        System.out.println("rowList is = " + rowList);
        Dataset<String> rowDatasetWithA = logData.filter((logData.col("value").contains("a")));
        List<String> rowWithA = rowDatasetWithA.collectAsList();
        System.out.println("rowWithA is = " + rowWithA);

        Dataset<String> rowDatasetWithB = logData.filter((logData.col("value").contains("b")));
        List<String> rowWithB = rowDatasetWithB.collectAsList();
        System.out.println("rowWithB is = " + rowWithB);

        long numAs = rowWithA.size();
        long numBs = rowWithB.size();
        System.out.println("Lines with a: " + numAs + ", lines with b: " + numBs);

        spark.stop();
    }
}
```

Assuming the content of `input.txt` to be this

```
a
b
c
a
aa
```

The output of the above snippet would be following

```
rowList is = [a, b, c, a, aa]
rowWithA is = [a, a, aa]
rowWithB is = [b]
Lines with a: 3, lines with b: 1
enter code here
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I still can't see the output of  System.out.println.  I think I have to initialize the log4j system.

Comment: After initializing the log4j system, I can see the following error message

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: App

Comment: How are you running your application? Some IDE or command-line?

Comment: I use command-line and I have resolved this problem by typing the correct class name. I make a stupid mistake.  Thanks for your comment.

Comment: You are welcome. Also, I hope you understood the mistake that you were making in your original code?